# How to filter web service results based on multiple parameters?

Tags: web-services, spring, rest, filter

To filter on multiple parameter I use this web service call :

```
http://mysite/sites/test/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Values?$filter=param1%20eq%20'test1'%20and%20param2%20eq%20'test2'
```

But how can I use this filter programmatically ?

To invoke the web service and to pass in the filter name and value in Java I use :

```
Map<String, String> variables = new HashMap<String, String>();
variables.put("filterName", "param1");
variables.put("filterValue", "test1");
```

and then invoke :

```
readOnlyRestTemplate.getForObject(url, String, variables);
```

This works fine for filtering on one parameter. But how can I filter based on multiple parameters, in this example include the name/value pair 'param2/test2' ?

Comment: This is more of a question for StackOverflow as it relates tot eh getForObject method and its overloads. It's not really a SharePoint question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter web service results based on multiple parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144586/how-to-filter-web-service-results-based-on-multiple-parameters)